# Image filesize becomes bigger after Upload (PHP, Joomla)

Tags: php, image, joomla, jpeg, joomla3.0

When I upload an Image with Joomla the .jpg has a much bigger filesize on the server than it had when it was on my harddrive. It usually is about 2-3 times bigger, although the dimensions are the same or smaller. Of course this is not good for the performance of the website. I could imagine that some library changes the compression of the image but I don't know where to start looking.

I use Joomla 3 and PHP 5.4 on an Apache Webserver.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, it sounds very unlikely that Joomla itself would alter the files on upload. I skimmed the code for uploading, but it uses standard functionality for all files. Are you using the normal media component to upload images, or some other addon? Uploads might be handled differently by different editors, like if you use img manager extended on JCE, you have the option to resize the image. Also, there might be active plugins altering the image after upload , there are triggers onContentBeforeSave and onContentAfterSave that might alter the image after upload.

Comment: Maybe give an example image url. Remember though files on disk have different reported sizes based on the smallest block size on a hard drive. Bigger hard drives have bigger blocks, so maybe 256k not 32k and code can be less but it still is written to those blocks